# Ubuntu font .otf format

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I have been unable to find an .otf version of the Ubuntu font family, only .ttf formats. I have downloaded the .ttf font files from the website.

Comment: You could convert the ttf fonts to otf if you need them in that format. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712047/how-can-i-convert-ttf-files-to-otf-format

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply convert the ttf files to otf? There are numerous ways of doing this. The are online services or you can use, or you could also install font forge `sudo apt-get install fontforge`
also available through the software center. The project page for font forge is here: http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/